# Нужно ли объяснять правила выбора гласных в корнях с чередованием А/О и Е/И?

Tags: орфография

Эти правила пользуются «заслуженным» вниманием в нашей орфографической науке по следующим причинам: 1. Мы их учим 10 лет и никак не можем выучить, хотелось бы потраченное время использовать с большей пользой. 2. Они компрометируют всю орфографию, так как все правила кажутся такими же произвольными и надуманными. 3. Они не учат нас творчески мыслить, а учат никак не мыслить и со всем соглашаться. Возможно, современный бунт молодежи против орфографии направлен не на сами  правила, а на их непонятность, необоснованность  и авторитарность. Поэтому предлагается обсудить три самых проблемных из них: выбор ЗАР/ЗОР, ПЛАВ/ПЛЫВ/ПЛОВ и РАСТ/РАЩ/РОС.  Если эти правила соответствуют принципам орфографии и мы не хотим их менять, то они должны получить обоснование,  – в противном случае их могут поменять другие, причем  без всякого объяснения. Предлагается использовать особое условие: современная орфография должна опираться на современную фонетику и современные толковые словари. Не имеет смысла обращаться к исторической фонетике (у этой науки другие задачи) и не имеет смысла апеллировать к Далю (он фиксировал лексику своего времени). Иначе говоря, правила должны быть понятны и актуальны  для современных носителей языка.
Вариант для  примера: корень ПЛАВ/ПЛОВ/ПЛЫВ – историческое чередование А/О/Ы совпадает с фонетическим чередованием А/О. Берем словарь: плыть - передвигаться  по поверхности воды или в воде, плавать  - то же, что плыть, но обозначает действие, совершающееся не в одно время, не за один прием  или не  в  одном  направлении.  Делаем вывод: плыть → плавать, плыть → пловец (чередование Ы/О), такое чередование встречается в языке: мыть – мою, 
крыть – крою. Получается, что "автором" правила является сам язык. Работа сделана, отдаем на проверку специалистам.  Возможно, они найдут ошибки, и тогда будем делать работу над ошибками.

Мысль такая: хотелось бы оставить слово «пловец» без изменения. Для этого надо объяснить, откуда берется О - иначе непонятно, кто и зачем  это исключение придумал.
Для объяснения желательно построить словообразовательную цепочку, например: плыть→ пловец, чередование Ы/О в корне, но соответствует ли  такое чередование действительным фонетическим процессам?
Или верен тот вариант, который вы предлагаете: плавать → пловчий→пловец, перегласовка А/О в ударной позиции.
Кстати, как определить понятие «перегласовка», чтобы придать слову вид узаконенного термина? Например: рассмотреть – рассматривать, это можно считать перегласовкой?

Comment: Скорее всего , *переогласовки* связаны с разными говорами. Банально где-то акают, а где-то окают. Корабли строили поморы, вот там и появились *плОвчие*, *плОвцы* и *плОвое дело*...

Comment: @Дерзкий, при оканьи есть различие между "о" а "а" в безударных позициях, под ударением звук произносится также.

Answer (score 2):

Немного недопонял Вашу мысль. Мыть - мою, выть - вою, а плЫть - плЫву! Где же в последнем примере чередование Ы-О?
**Чередование А-О в корнях плав/плов** :
плавать, плаватель, плавни, вплавь, плавучий, плавный, на плаву - плОвчий (мореплаватель), плОвый (относящийся к постройке судов), плОвец... Последнее слово означало мореплавателя, моряка, помощника кормчего (СлРЯ 11-17 вв), потом ударение и значение поменялись, но офография осталась прежней. Имеет ли смысл писать сейчас *плавец* вместо *пловец*, чтобы избавиться от единственного в современных словарях исключения в "плавательном" семействе? Филологи очень любят традиционные написания, лишнее правило с единственным примером для них прямо рахат-лукум)))
Легче будет возродить забытые слова пловчий и пловый, чем переучивать на **плавца**. Можно подумать и предложить новые значения : пловчий - тренер пловцов (главный пловчий), пловый - легко держащийся на воде, непотопляемый??

РОСТ-РАЩ-РОС. Приведу школьное правило :

> "В корне   -рос- / -раст- (-ращ-)   на месте безударного гласного
> перед   с  пишется буква   о ,
> перед  ст, щ   –   буква а
> росли   –   растение   –  приращение
> **Исключения** :
> отрасль,   росток,   на вырост,   ростовщик,  
> Ростов,   Ростислав   и   слова,   от   них   образованные...""

Смешные "исключения" *росток, на вырост, ростовщик* легко объясняются происхождением от слова *рост* с ударной О. Надо детям побольше объяснять связи слов, их этимологию - вместо тупого заучивания правил и исключений из оных.
Рассмотрим семейства слов с корнями рос/рост(рощ)/раст(ращ).
**Рос** - рОслый, взрОслый,малорОслый, поросль, заросль, росли, росла, росло, рОс (вырос, зарОс, подрОс, перерос, врос, изрос, порос, дорос, недорОс...) + причастия (зарОсший...)
Все гнездо происходит от глагола прошедшего времени "рос". Много имеется словоформ с ударной О, проблемы проверки нет. *Рос* - всегда *рОс.* **Отрасль** - единственное исключение.
**Рост** (рощ) - рОст, нарОст, вырост, перерОсток, ростовщик (деньги в рОст), ростовка, подрОсток, росток, рОща, прорОщенный, отрОсток...
**Ростъ** - "степень высоты..." (САР) Корень *рост* имеет смысл объективной величины, то есть высоты.
**Раст** (ращ) - *рАстъ*, растение, возраст, расти (зарасти, подрасти...), растить, вырАщивать, отрАщивать, срАщивать,  ращу, приращение, 
**Растъ** - "пора, время поспевания" (САР) "*Теперь самой **растъ** хлебу...*" Корень *раст* имеет отношение ко времени и, скажем так, развитию (возраст, растить...) Растение развивается из семени, его растят согласно погодным сезонам. Ребенка растят (примерно так же)))
Мои рассуждения достаточно схематичны, но они хотя бы показывают, откуда что берется. Голые школьные правила не объясняют ничего.